# How to cluster polylines?

Tags: android-maps-extensions

I have been trying this great library for a month now. It allows me to have more than 5000 markers on the map so far. The problem is that I have to draw polylines betweens these locations. Please does anyone has an example on how to cluster polylines? When I don't draw the polylines, the zoom (and the map) is smooth, but as soon as I draw polylines it becomes slow.
Please mg6maciej (the author of the library), do you have any Demo on how to cluster polylines?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow. There are many ways polygon or polyline clustering might be implemented. Certainly more complex then marker clustering, where every item has only one LatLng. I encourage you to try implementing your requirements and ask questions if you get stuck somewhere.